# How to zoom view in objectaid eclipse plugin for UML?

Tags: eclipse, objectaid

I'm using the objectaid eclipse plugin to get diagram class for my java project.

I can't find a way to zoom the view, I can zoom out by pressing `Ctrl + "-"`, but I can't zoom in by pressing `Ctrl + "+"`.

Have any one idea?

[image]

Comment: crtl "+" works for me

Answer (score 2):

I'm using macbook pro. The standard key cmd + "-" and cmd + "=" works for zoom in and zoom out. You may want to check if those keys are mapped to other functions with eclipse or OS (windows or mac).

Answer (score 1):

I found in my eclipse (2018-12) a very tiny zoom dropdown, which made it possible to zoom back to e.g. 100%. But the default shortcut (Ctrl + '+' or Ctrl + Shift + '+') did not work for me, either.

[image]